# Как сделать выполнение скрипта каждые n секунд (api vk + cron)?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, cron

Всем доброго вечера.

Имеется скрипт, который отвечает на сообщения ВКонтакте, по тому, есть нужда делать это быстро.

В кроне есть скрипт

```
wget -O /dev/null -q 'https://site.ru/vk.php'
```

который за один запуск может делать до 9 операций (запросов в вк).

Как сделать так, чтобы скрипт срабатывал каждые 10 - 15 секунд, при этом небыло сильной нагрузки на сервер и не получить бан от вк.

Пробовала такой вариант

```
while true; do wget -O /dev/null -q 'https://site.ru/vk.php' sleep 5; done
```

В итоге - повис сервер + бан от вк. А так

```
while true; do wget -O /dev/null -q 'https://site.ru/vk.php' sleep 10; done
```

просто бан от вк.

Сам принцип работы скрипта - получаем 10 непрочитанных диалогов, получаем у каждого диалога последнее сообщение, массивом пробегаемся по содержимому сообщений и в зависимости от содержимого - отправляем ответ.

За ранее спасибо.

Comment: Для ответов на личные сообщения лучше использовать опросы https://vk.com/dev/using_longpoll. А у вас перед sleep есть точка с запятой?

Comment: Нет, нету точки с запятой

Comment: @mymedia, нюанс еще в том, что я сначала проверяю есть ли новые сообщения (1 запрос) и если есть - в зависимости от их количества, выполняю дальнейшие действия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`;` это разделитель команд. Без `;` у вас просто задержки нет. Попробуйте вот так

```
while true; do wget -O /dev/null -q 'https://site.ru/vk.php'; sleep 5; done
```

Comment: Спасибо, это решило мою проблему